# how to test a function inside a class [python, pyCharm]

Tags: python, function, class, call

i am teaching myself coding right now via the udacity.web_development course. my coding is geting allright but i regularly have problems that are related to the process and not the code.

like right now:
i dont know how to test this function (passwort_check) while it is inside a class. i cant call it. 
when i put "print MainHandler.passwort_check((self or MainHandler), "string")" in the bottom it gives me a type error.

i know right now all this webhandlerstuff is useless. but i need it there for later. to comment everything out, but the one function i need cannot be the right solution.

this is my code:

```
import webapp2
import re


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

    def passwort_check(self, passwort_string):
        if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$", passwort_string):
            print passwort_string
        else: print "change pw"

    print MainHandler.passwort_check(MainHandler,"hallo")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                  ('/', MainHandler)
                              ], debug=True)
```

this is my error:

> TypeError: unbound method passwort_check() must be called with MainHandler instance as first > argument (got type instance instead)

but my question is more generall: how do you guys or professionals/experianced coders do codevalidation in this case

Comment: You should really include the details of the error in your question.  Otherwise, we can only guess as to what the error might be.

Comment: i put this at the bottom of the file: print MainHandler.passwort_check(MainHandler,"hallo")

Comment: this comes out: TypeError: unbound method passwort_check() must be called with MainHandler instance as first argument (got type instance instead)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of class MainHandler first. Like:

```
my_handler = MainHandler()
```

Then invoke function in it. Like:

```
my_handler.passwort_check('passwort_string')
```

If you need to do some `unittest` for this. Check this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). It will give you some instructions.

Hope it helps.:)

Answer (score 2):

Given that `MainHandler.passwort_check` does nothing with the `self` parameter, you could -- at least for now -- define it as a [*static method*](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods). Unlike normal methods declared inside a class definition, static methods do not implicitly receive the instance upon which they are called as their first argument. In fact, they need not be called on any instance at all.

```
@staticmethod  # This is called a "decorator"
def passwort_check(passwort_string)  # Omit self from the parameters
    # The rest of your code remains the same
```

Then you can simply call it the way you were doing, but you don't need to dummy an instance to pass as the first parameter.

```
MainHandler.passwort_check('string')
```

should work fine.

(Of course, if you just want to test the regex, it might be easier to simply use a regex tester site like [Regex101](http://regex101.com).)